# wait until method finishes then go on next lines Android

Tags: android, google-maps, asynchronous, methods

I have a method that downloads some data including coordinates of locations from API and populates an array. I am calling this method in `onCreate` then in `onMapReady` I am calling another method which puts the markers on map. I only have 2 test items to add to my map now so it doesn't take much time to download them and show, however still sometimes it runs the later method before I am done downloading the data. so it shows no markers.

I tried different approaches such as AsyncTask but this one always runs the later method before first one is finished.

here's my code

```
private class AsynchronouslyDoSomeStuff extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.v("Donkey", "Async doInBackground Called");
        downloadCustomersData();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Log.v("Donkey", "Async onPostExecute Called");
        updateMapMarkers();
    }
}
```

and then calling `new AsynchronouslyDoSomeStuff().execute();` in `onMapReady` but as I said it doesn't work.

Note: I don't want to use things like `Thread.wait(some time);` because I don't know how much time it takes later for different customers.

Comment: The code you have posted will do exactly what you need but only if `downloadCustomersData()` is synchronous.  If it is asynchronous then it will not complete before `onPostExecute` is called.  It really all depends on what `downloadCustomersData` is doing.

Comment: @Kuffs it is not possible to perform synchronous network operations on the main thread. That would lead to a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Comment: This is an AsyncTask and not the main thread therefore network operations are permitted both synchronously and asynchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my question by calling the second method as a callback function of the first method.

and then calling the first method in onLocationChanged of my map.

I called the second method right after for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from my comment above.  A much easier (in my opinion) method of doing this type of thing is the EventBus model.

Please see: http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/

Using this, you can just fire events whenever you want to update your UI.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is call a method as soon as two asynchronous tasks have completed (`onMapReady` and `doInBackground`).

The easiest way to do that is store the result of the task which finishes first, and then execute the method when the second one finishes.

e.g.

```
if(customerData == null) {
    this.googleMap = googleMap;
} else {
    setMapMarkers(customerData, googleMap);
}
```

---

```
if(googleMap == null) {
    this.customerData = customerData;
} else {
    setMapMarkers(customerData, googleMap);
}
```